# Disabling payment methods based on custom shipping methods in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, shipping-method

In WooCommerce shop I have 2 delivery method based on Parcel locker. The first is payable in advance, while the second is cash on delivery.

The idea is:

- easypack_parcel_machines -> only Pay in advance
- easypack_parcel_machines_cod -> only Cash on delivery

My code below. After applying in both cases, I only have Pay in advance. What's wrong?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'gateway_disable_shipping_meth' );
  
function gateway_disable_shipping_meth( $available_gateways ) {
   if ( ! is_admin() ) {
      $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );      
      $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];
      
       if ( isset( $available_gateways['bacs'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'easypack_parcel_machines' ) ) {
         unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
      }
      elseif ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'easypack_parcel_machines_cod' ) ) {
         unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
      }
   }  
   return $available_gateways;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both shipping methods start with the same slug, you should simply need to invert them in your if / elseif statement as follows *(also there are some other mistake)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'gateway_disable_shipping_meth' );
  
function gateway_disable_shipping_meth( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $chosen_shipping = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];
      
        if ( isset( $available_gateways['bacs'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'easypack_parcel_machines_cod' ) ) {
            unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
        }
        elseif ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'easypack_parcel_machines' ) ) {
            unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
        }
    }  
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

or also this way too:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'gateway_disable_shipping_meth' );
  
function gateway_disable_shipping_meth( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $chosen_shipping = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];
        
        if ( 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'easypack_parcel_machines' ) ) {
            if ( false !== strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'cod' ) && isset( $available_gateways['bacs'] ) ) {
                unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
            } elseif ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) ) {
                unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
            }
        }
    }  
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: I had a feeling that a similar slug can cause problems. Your code works great. Thanks for your help.